# Can a single acpi driver work for two devices where one is normal device and another is platform device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, acpi

I want to understand if it is possible to have a single driver shared between following two devices. E.g. from the ACPI tables, the two devices are mapped as follows:

```asl
Scope (\_SB)
{
    Device (XYZ)
    {
        Name (_HID, "XYZ123")  // _HID: Hardware ID
        Name (_UID, "XYZ")  // _UID: Unique ID
        Method (_DIS, 0, NotSerialized)  // _DIS: Disable Device
        {
        }

        Method (_DSM, 4, Serialized)  // _DSM: Device-Specific Method
        {
        }
        ...
   }
}

Scope (\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.ABC)
{
    OperationRegion (PCIM, SystemMemory,)

    Method (_DSM, 4, Serialized)  // _DSM: Device-Specific Method
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

IIUC, device XYZ is platform device and device ABC is discoverable PCI device.

I need to access _DSM method of Device (XYZ) using the ACPI driver of device ABC (_SB.PCI0.PEG0.ABC). From https://lwn.net/Articles/367630/ I understand that in order to write ACPI driver for a device we need to have following

```c
static const struct acpi_device_id bt_device_ids[] = {
  { "TOS6205", 0},
  { "", 0},
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(acpi, bt_device_ids);

static struct acpi_driver toshiba_bt_driver = {
    .name =         "Toshiba BT",
    .class =        "Toshiba",
    .ids =          bt_device_ids,
    .ops =          {
                            .add =    toshiba_bt_rfkill_add,
                            .remove = toshiba_bt_rfkill_remove,
                    },
    .owner =    THIS_MODULE,
};
```

I was wondering if adding a new additional entry in 'acpi_device_id' will help with the same 'acpi_driver'. Also why we add an extra null entry `{ "", 0}` for 'acpi_device_id'? I understand that each device has to register itself with ACPI and also register for notifiers to receive any notifications from ACPI, I found https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/acpi/enumeration.txt but I could not understand it completely. Is there a way that already existing driver for device ABC can be modified to access `_DSM()` functions of XYZ device?

Comment: 1. If you need what you are telling, something is heavily broken in your system. In general each of the drivers should take care about its own realm. `_DSM()` method should be called in a scope of the certain driver and it's result converted to something which is abstract enough to be modeled in the Linux kernel.

Comment: 2. The *ACPI drivers* are legacy and shouldn't be created anymore. Instead regular platform driver infrastructure should suffice to fulfill the task.

Comment: 3. `{ "", 0}` entry or i.o.w. *Terminator entry* is to show the end of the array. Otherwise each time one must to supply a supplementary parameter of length of the array. Taking into account zillions of users of the API it's not practical. Note, that the table resides in a special section in the binary and it will require to have a complex structure to pass, like a header per driver.

Comment: 4. What exactly is unclear in *enumeration.txt* (which is by the way a bit outdated, new kernels have switched to reST format and on the site it's represented in HTML form)?

Comment: 5. As per 1. I can add that it may be also misdesign issue if you are creating a new table for some new device. But in any case, calling someone's else `_DSM()` sounds very wrong to start with.

Comment: @0andriy Thanks for your reply!

1> In this experiment, both of the devices involved belong to the same owner, one is pci device and the other one is a software device.

2> can you please reference an example for the latest approach that does not involve legacy ACPI driver.

3> thanks, I understand now.

Comment: What _software device_ means? It's clearly misdesigned architecture.